# is it possible to impliment expandablelistview in which each child has different item/layouts

Tags: android, layout, expandablelistview

First of all, I'm new to programming. Is it possible to create custom expandable list in each child that has a different layout? If yes, please help me out!

1. There are three parents, each having a textview and a switch.

   2. The child of first parent has:

      1. textview
      2. Seekbar
      3. edittext
   3. The child of second parent has:

      1. textview
      2. timepicker
      3. textview
      4. edittext
   4. The child of third parent has:

      1. textview
      2. edittext

Please check this photoshop mockup, which is want I'd like to impliment:

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8bqii0d4vt43wa8/changed%20layout.jpg]

- Should I create three different XML for each child, or is it the adapter who plays a role here?
- If not possible with expandable list, HOW can I implement this ?
- Any suggestion to guide, tutorial is appreciated. :)

Comment: Yes you can, but you have to inflate the respective layouts by considering the positions individually

Comment: thanks bro! i sort of understand

Comment: @PrasanthS, I'm sorry to tag you on an irrelevant question, but when performing tag wiki edits, please **don't** just edit in a dictionary definition without looking at how the tag is actually used.  For example, you recently submitted an edit for [tag:cv2] where the only use was nothing like your proposed wiki.  In that case, the question was edited to use a more correct tag.  You could have performed that edit instead of creating a misleading wiki excerpt.  Edit tags with care, please!

Answer (score 0):

You can in a custom adapter but you have to create the respective layouts. Use something like the following in your getView() method.

```
switch (groupPosition) {
     case 0:
         convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group1, null);
         break;
     case 1:
         convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group2, null);
         break;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response bro! so i have to create three layout for each child ? like child_1.xml, child_2.xml,child_3.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using two types of views of children items of the group. So you have to override the following two methods

```
final int CHILDVIEW_ONE = 0;
final int CHILDVIEW_TWO = 1;
final int CHILDVIEW_TYPE_COUNT = CHILDVIEW_TWO + 1;
@Override
public int getChildTypeCount() {
    return CHILDVIEW_TYPE_COUNT;
}


@Override
public int getChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
{
      if(childObject instanceOf item1)
         return CHILDVIEW_ONE;
      else if (childObject instance item2)
         return CHILDVIEW_TWO;
return super.getChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition);
}
```

Then in your `getChildView()` Do the following:

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     ....
     if(childObject instanceOf item1){
         //handle the first child view
     }else if (childObject instanceOf item2){
         //handle the second child view
     }
     ....
}
```

**You have to override both getChildType and getChildTypeCount in order to use the concept of viewholders which optimizes the Memory peroformance drawing a scrollview**